# Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. .htaccess is not redirecting requests

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

when i visit `localhost/project` I get this error

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

when i try to access project root directory, my `index.php` is in `public` folder `(project/public/index.php)` so i use `.htaccess` to redirect requests to public folder but this doesn't seem to work 
i tried to set `AllowOverride All` but didn't help 
i tried to change all project permissions even to `777` still didn't work

here is my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

    RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

i am using ubuntu 18.08 - PHP 7.3 - Apache

Comment: @anubhava it's in project root directory .. the same error when i remove .htaccess,, when i hit `localhost/project/public` it works but with errors as style doesn't work and always return 404 page

Comment: Does `/project/public/` also have a .htaccess ?

Comment: @anubhava i didn't at first .. then added one to hit index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have this in `/project/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /project/%1 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Then have this rule in `project/public/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your project folder .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)/?$ public/index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```